# How to highlight/outline buttons on Android (for TV box)?

Tags: android-tv

I bought a Android TV box and the biggest problem I'm having is to use apps that wasn't made for tv cause I can't control it using the Tv box's remote control.

See this image, it's the homescreen of a tv box. 
[image]
[image]

As you can see, Kodi app is highlighted in the first image, and Music app in the second, and you can move that outline using the remote control buttons to select other apps.

The biggest problem is that apps that wasn't made to Tv have not that outline. Is there any way to add it to apps that don't have it?

I've tried Google TalkBack, it does that in my phone but somehow I couldn't install in on my tv box (and it don't select just buttons and inputs by all elements in the app, like text and images)...